# Probability of bankruptcy

Tags: probability

I have damage distribution:

[image]

There $Z$ is a damage and $\Bbb P$ is its probability. Each week, the insurer receives a premium of about $2,000$. The initial capital is $8,000$. How to estimate the probability of bankruptcy of an insurer company over a period of one week, over a period of 3 weeks, over a period of $20$ weeks?
I found several formulas in my notes, but its for $\Bbb E(Z)<1$. Can I suppose that $1=2000$ and change my distribution?

Comment: So essentially you're summing discrete random variables together, and you want to know their sum (which is also a random variable). When the amount of weeks is large, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: If you divide all the monetary amounts in the question by $1000$ then the probabilities stay the same

Comment: Oh, I wrote the wrong number. What about 1=2000?

Comment: @MattiP.: The central limit theorem can be used to approximate the probability that the company has non-negative capital after a large number of weeks. It's not immediately clear how it could be used to approximate the probability that the company goes bankrupt, since this may occur because of having negative capital at some intermediate point, not necessarily at the end of the period.